# IE8 style.top limited to 1342177?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Found this rather strange bug in IE8; element.style.top is limited to 1342177 pixels.
Even though an element will rarely grow this large, it is not impossible. And when it does things break. (I am an unfortunate victim)

Any possible work arounds you guys can think of?

Comment: At 96 dots per inch, 1342177 Pixels is approx. *355 metres* (388 yards). That is approx. 1.267 screenfuls on a 24" widescreen monitor. When will one need that kind of pixel value? O_o

Comment: @Pekka Yes, it is very improbable. In my case I have a grid rendered without pagination and when datasize grows to 50k+ things start breaking.

Comment: I see. I would have thought that IE crashes and burns before ever reaching that limit :) Live and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good catch! This seems to be a new limitation in IE8 that wasn't present in previous versions. It occurs even in IE7-compatibility and Quirks modes.

It's not just `top`: it seems to affect all CSS lengths. Looks like a number-parsing problem, in that I can get a larger measurement by using another unit, but the number is still the maximum (eg. `1342177em` gives the same height as `2000000em`).

You can also put a positioned element with `top: (more)px;` inside another positioned element with `top: 1342177px;`, of course.